# Form with file filed in CakePHP

Tags: file, cakephp, forms

How get name of field type file in beforeSave()?
I have form with many file filed, and i must get names of each...

Comment: Your question is unclear and you have some confusing typos (file filed?).  Please rephrase.

Comment: No. I would like get name of data[ModelName][get_this_name][tmp_name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that obviously depends on what name you give it. If that's unknown, you can simply loop through the data array and pick the one that looks like a file array:

```
foreach ($this->data[$this->alias] as $field => $contents) {
    if (isset($contents['tmp_name'])) {
        // This is the $field you're looking for
    }
}
```